# Difference of divergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's consider the series
$$s(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{x}{\ln n}\right).$$

I want to prove it diverges for all $x$. To do that I want to compare to some harmonic series but I don't know how to start. Any idea about how to do that?

In a more particular case, I'm interested when $x=1$.

I tried to express it like this this:

$$s(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\ln n- nx}{n\ln n} $$
but it doesn't seem to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $x\le0$ is easy, since each term in the series will exceed $\frac1n$. For the case $x>0$, the terms in your series are eventually all negative (why?) so you should prove that
$$
\sum \left(\frac x{\ln n} - \frac1n\right)
$$
diverges to $\infty$. To prove that, argue that
$$
 \frac x{\ln n} - \frac1n>\frac1n
$$
for all $n$ sufficiently large (exactly how large depends on $x$), which follows from
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}n = 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $x=1$

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{\ln n}\right)=-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{\ln n}-\frac{1}{n}\right) \quad f(n)=\frac{1}{\ln n}-\frac{1}{n}>0$$

then by [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

$$ 0 \ \leq\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)\ \leq\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n}f(2^{n})\ \leq\ 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$$

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{\ln n}-\frac{1}{n}\right)\ge\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2^n}{\ln 2^n}-\frac{2^n}{2^n}\right)=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{2^n}{n\ln 2}-1\right)=\infty$$

For the general case note that eventually $\forall x\in \mathbb{R^+}$ (the case $x\le0$ is trivial)

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{x}{\ln n}\right)=-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{\ln n}-\frac{1}{n}\right) \quad f(n)=\frac{x}{\ln n}-\frac{1}{n}>0$$

then apply the condensation test.